# comm command gives faulty output?

Tags: shell, unix, comm

I have two files which just list a bunch of different file names on each line. I merged them, sorted them, and then checked the `comm` output and noticed something really interesting.

```
$ sort -u -o list1 list1
$ sort -u -o list2 list2
$ cat list1 list2 > combined
$ wc -l list1 
  18141 list1
$ wc -l list2 
  21755 list2
$ wc -l combined 
  39896 combined
$ sort -u -o combined combined 
$ wc -l combined 
  24400 combined


$ comm -23 list1 combined | wc -l
  12889
$ comm -13 list1 combined | wc -l
  19148
$ comm -12 list1 combined | wc -l
   5252


$ comm -23 list2 combined | wc -l
      0
$ comm -13 list2 combined | wc -l
   2645
$ comm -12 list2 combined | wc -l 
  21755
```

(line breaks above for clarity)

What's going on with those last few calls to `comm`? When I compare `list1` to `combined` the output is wacky, but when I compare `list2` to `combined` the output seems fine.

I even tried to combine all three lists again and test:

```
$ cat list1 list2 combined > combined-again
$ wc -l combined-again 
  64296 combined-again
$ sort -u -o combined-again combined-again
$ wc -l combined-again 
  24400 combined-again
$ diff combined combined-again
```

The sorted unique line count of `combined` and `combined-again` match, and there is no output from `diff`!

```
$ comm combined combined-again | wc -l
  24400
$ comm -12 combined combined-again | wc -l
  24400
$ comm -3 combined combined-again | wc -l
      0
```

These `comm` outputs make sense, there shouldn't be any difference between the two files.

```
$ comm -23 list1 combined-again | wc -l
  12889
$ comm -13 list1 combined-again | wc -l
  19148
$ comm -12 list1 combined-again | wc -l
   5252
```

When comparing against `list1`, we see the same wonky numbers again.

```
$ comm -23 list2 combined-again | wc -l                     
      0
$ comm -13 list2 combined-again | wc -l
   2645
$ comm -12 list2 combined-again | wc -l
  21755
```

When comparing against `list2`, the numbers are appropriate and correct.

I even used the some lines of output from `comm -23 list1 combined-again` to `grep` for those lines in `combined-again`, and those lines do exist. I'm totally at a loss for why the `comm` output is faulty in this case...

#### EDIT1:

```
$ locale
  LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_ALL=
```

Each of the files don't contain weird symbols or characters, just package names using camel case. For example:

```
$ head list1
  AAAAuthentication
  AAACorrelationAPI
  AAACorrespondence
  AAATestSuite
  AESDescription
  AESImplementation
  AESLogging
  AESMaster
  AESProofSystem
  AESTestSuite
```

#### EDIT2:

After some more investigation due to some suggestions in the comments, it seems that the issue could be because of the versioning of the `comm` and `sort` tools.

I ran all of the above commands on mac, where `comm` is from BSD January 26, 2005, and `sort` is from GNU coreutils, sort 5.93 on November 2005.

On the linux box, both `comm` and `sort` are from GNU coreutils 8.4 of January 2012, and the calls work perfectly.

I guess the question now is: what's the discrepancy between the versioning, and why does it affect the `comm` output as shown above?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the files.  What sort of characters do they contain?  What does the `locale` command report?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added the `locale` output and sample file contents

Comment: If this is GNU coreutils `comm`, I suggest using `comm --check-order`

Comment: hm, I'm using the BSD `comm`

Comment: Interesting... on the GNU `comm` it says that `list2` is not in order, even though I had used `sort`....

Comment: Found out some interesting things about the versioning differences, and updated the question

Comment: The different tools probably have different ideas of what "sorted" means. If you get rid of the locale (run `LC_ALL=C sort ...` and `LC_ALL=C comm ...`) that might help

Comment: Awesome!! That was the solution, thanks so much! Now I have to go learn a little about locales....

Comment: Is there a way I can upvote or accept that answer?

Comment: It's not really an answer (I don't know what's going on in the en_US locale) it's more of a dodge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `comm` to work, its input needs to be sorted. And it needs to agree with your `sort` on what sorting method to use. In the C locale (`LC_ALL=C`) this is easy. Strings are compared one byte at a time, and the first byte that's different determines the order.

In the `en_US.UTF-8` locale, it's harder. First of all, there's no single authority describing what exactly the expected behavior is. Every vendor is free to imagine what "English sort order, US variant" means. And then document that decision or not (usually they pick "not"). And when your tools are half from BSD, half from GNU, the chance for disagreement is increased (though theoretically, I think they both should defer to the local C library...)

Running all your commands with `LC_ALL=C` should make them more likely to agree with each other.